# Can we use the Residue theorem to calculate this integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

The integral is as follows.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} z^{-it-\delta/2-1}\left(\frac{1}{|z-1|^{1-\alpha}}-\frac{1}{|1+z|^{1-\alpha}}\right)dz
$$
For example, we can suppose $0<\delta<1$, $0<\alpha<1$, $2\alpha<\delta$. Lemma 2.1 in this this paper can give us some clue. However, I can't continue, because $|1\pm z|^{1-\alpha}$ are multivalued function. New Contour is needed.

the paper can be find in this website.
[Formation of Singularities for a Transport Equation with Nonlocal Velocity](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20159946?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)

Comment: Did you forget to attach a link to your paper? What  is Lemma 2.1?

Comment: Sorry, I add it now.